# using eclipse to consume WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I'm trying to consume a WSDL of a web service using eclipse luna. During the process of consuming the WSDL the following warning as are prompted:

```
The input type org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.EVS_IPDirector_Logic_LogicIPWSInterface_AutoComplete.WsField_V01 is a non-instantiable type and will be omitted from the sample JSP.  Continue with sample JSP generation?
```

When I try to invoke the operation the following exception is throw. How can I resolve this?

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/dcrearer/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.

An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit


Feb 24, 2015 1:27:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit


Feb 24, 2015 1:27:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception


Feb 24, 2015 1:27:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.sampleIIPWS_005fV01Proxy.Result_jsp


Feb 24, 2015 1:27:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit



Feb 24, 2015 1:27:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.sampleIIPWS_005fV01Proxy.Result_jsp

Feb 24, 2015 1:27:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.sampleIIPWS_005fV01Proxy.Result_jsp
```

Comment: Your message is bigger than the configured allow maximum size value. The details are in the error log.

Comment: @Namphibian not very familiar with the eclipse IDE. How do I change the value?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the wsdl? Seems like it is generating a huge JSP for some reason.

Comment: @Namphibian the WSDL is very large. I'm actually generating it from the service endpoint. Similar to how it is done in microsoft visual studio.

Comment: There is a limitation on the size of a single method in the JVM read this article http://architects.dzone.com/articles/understanding-jvm-internals it seems like the WSDL is generating extremely large classes. Can you confirm this?